# Click on a button by using Rosource Id in robotium scripts

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I need a help regarding robotium scripts.

I have the source code for the `button`

```
Button btnCreateTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateTask);
```

I want to click on button using `robotium`
I used the following code for it

```
Button CTButton = solo.getView(R.id.btnCreateTask);
solo.clickOnView(CTButton);
```

But I am getting an error like "btnCreateTask cannot be resolved or is not a field"
Can anyone please help me why this error is coming.
Is this the correct way I am using?
Thanks

Comment: try adding your package name in front of id your.package.R.id.btnCreateTask

Comment: check you haven't import android.r i your activity.

Comment: After adding package name It showing "id cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Import android.r statement is already added.

Answer (score 2):

Correct code is:

```
Button CTButton = solo.getView("btnCreateTask");
solo.clickOnView(CTButton);
```

Comment: Thanks Flavio. It works.                                             Button CTButton =(Button) solo.getView("btnCreateTask");
solo.clickOnView(CTButton);

Comment: Agian i got one issue like i have an imageview ImageView topbarCalender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pf_topbarCalender);    I want to click on it the same way button.But my test is failing.Is it the correct way to access the ImageView